# how to get src element in javascript for firefox

Tags: javascript

I am try to catch form event in javascript

```
var event = window.event.srcElement;
```

This is working fine in IE, but in
Netscape/Firefox where event return undefined.

Can someone tel me how to catch event
in Netscape/Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

IE and Netscape play different games.
But you can easily make it crossbrowser as such:

```
if (window.event) e = window.event;
var srcEl = e.srcElement? e.srcElement : e.target;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
var event = event.target;
```

Or to check for both/fallback in a single statement:

```js
function myHandler(event) {
  var target = window.event.srcElement || event.target;
}
```

(In both cases... I'd rename your variable, since this isn't the actual `event` object, but an element.)

Comment: It is now work. When it is catches, event is work. I want to work this event.

Comment: In Firefox, there is no `window.event`.

Comment: @Tim - oops, good point, this is why I always use a layer above, normalizing at least this and `which`/`keyCode` behavior.